# Are questions about Spanish certification tests on-topic?

Tags: discusión, ámbito

We have a new question about a Spanish certification test: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8425/12

Should this be on-topic here?

We have a policy against learning resources, and this seems related on the one hand, but on the other questions about a specific standardized exam could be more specific.

Note that I'm not advocating for re-opening this question *as it is*--it's still too broad to be a good (single) question here.  But before I work with the OP to polish up the question for re-opening, I want to know how the community feels about this topic in general.

Comment: We can have in the faq a list of the most important ceritifcation in spanish, like english `TOEFL`. I dont know any spanish certification, but I think other members could know some certification in Europe or LATAM.

Comment: @EmilioGort: Maybe I'm naive, but isn't DELE C1 some sort of certification? In any case, should questions about this be on topic? Or do we stick strictly to to the study of the language (grammar, pronunciation, etc)?

Comment: I think yes, this is the first time I hear about it, but is just my ignorance about this topic, my proposal is make a list of them in the faq or some comunity wiki, we dont have any comunity wiki from what I see

Comment: The problem with make on topic this kind of question, is that you will see a milli9n of question is this phrase correct? In x test

Comment: Yeah, I'm really not sure what a *good* question about an exam would be like. I suppose `Do grade review petitions have an effect on the Oral Section at all?` could be an objective question about such an exam, for instance.

Comment: It looks like ELU has a [single TOEFL question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10072/9983), which was closed as a duplicate to a now-deleted question. heh.

Comment: Hazla en español no entiendo bien la pregunta q pusiste

Comment: @EmilioGort: Mi pregunta es: Queremos hacer preguntas sobre examenes así "on-topic", o queremos solo preguntas sobre el *idioma* (gramatica, pronunciacion, etc)? Es dificil pensar en una pregunta "buena" sobre examenes, pero quizás `Peticiones de revista de califiaciones tienen un afecto en el parte oral del examen?` puede ser un ejemplo de una pregunta más o menos "buena" sobre un examen.

Comment: me referia a `Do grade review petitions have an effect on the Oral Section at all?` y tu traduccion me dejo mas confuso todavia...lol, pero en definitivas pienso que no serian buenas preguntas, yo las dejaría off topic, e incuiria en los faq o en una comunity wiki un listado de las certificaciones mas importantes

Comment: @EmilioGort: Pues, quizás mi traduccion es mala... jaja. Es una pregunta de la pregunta que yo cerré. No sé como traducirolo mejor. Si quieres venir a Chat, puedo intentar :)

Comment: Cerré la pregunta porque pedía consejo sobre qué hacer en su situación en concreto, la pregunta no es acerca del castellano. En mi opinión, es como si alguien viaja a México, la policía le pone una multa de tráfico y luego pide aquí consejo por ser México un país de habla hispana. Realmente no veo la relevancia de que sea un examen de español para pedir aquí consejo sobre qué hacer por haber suspendido el examen.

Comment: Why is this question appearing in the top of the list of questions this often? I don't see anything happening in [its timeline](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/368/timeline).

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo: de [who is the Community user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/209901) _Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped. The Community User will only bump a maximum of one question per hour._

Comment: Insofar as the question is about Spanish grammar, it's fine. However, looking for correct answers is not. Like a test.

Answer (score 0):

Soy el preguntador de la pregunta original. Parece que obtuve un downvote en la dicha pregunta y ahora tengo 48 reputación y no puedo comentar jaja...

La cuestión es que obtuve una puntaje baja sobre la sección oral del examen DELE, lo que considero injusto y lo que me dejó calificado como "no apto" para el certificado DELE por una falta de 1.67 puntos... Entonces considero solicitar una revisión. Sin embargo, como el resultado de la revisión llegará después de dos meses, a cual tiempo ya empezca una nueva convocatoria del examen, quiero gastar mi tiempo preparando para el nuevo examen en lugar de esperar para el resultado, si es que la solicitud de revisión normalmente no será estimada. Por eso quiero preguntar si alguien tiene alguna sabiduría/experiencia sobre este tema y quizás me pueda ayudar.

Ahora, sobre este tema, en todas maneras no creo que aparecerían un million de preguntas sobre el examen DELE... Siempre podemos aplicar nuestra criteria sobre preguntas de SE, es decir una pregunta debería ser concreta y no subjetiva etc. Y de hecho mucha gente necesita ayuda sobre el examen.